# group rows by two variables, sort column values by list, then concatenate

Tags: r, sorting, concatenation

I have a dataframe (DF1) in R in long format with ~430,000 rows and 4 columns. I want to group the observations by file, then Name, followed by sorting in a certain order defined by a list and then concatenate the values in column GT. The table has this format:

```
# Assay Name  GT  file
# as1   Fred  AG  file1.csv
# as2   Fred  GT  file1.csv
# as3   Fred  TC  file1.csv
# as2   Curt  AG  file1.csv
# as1   Curt  GG  file1.csv
# as3   Curt  TT  file1.csv
# as1   Fred  AG  file2.csv
# as2   Fred  NA  file2.csv
# as3   Fred  TC  file2.csv
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
# Name   GT_concatenated  
# Fred   AGGTTC
# Curt   GGAGTT
# Fred   AG  TC
```

That means that the Assay column needs to be sorted by this list first c("as1","as2","as3") and then concatenated. I have tried this:

```
DF2<-aggregate(GT~file+Name,data=DF1,paste,collapse="")
```

which gives me the desired output, but not sorted and no blank spaces for the 'NA' values.

Comment: I had an answer but I deleted it as I'm not sure I understand your desired output.  The Fred file1 row seems like it ougt to be AGGTTC, but you've listed it as GTAGGT.  This appears to go as2, as1, as3, which I don't understand.

Comment: @HarlandMason I would go ahead and post your answer, since it's likely a typo. You can edit your answer upon further clarification

Comment: Yes, typo on that one. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I do a data operation by a column, I turn to data.table

```
library('data.table')

DF1 <- as.data.table(DF1)
```

Let's sort the data by file, Name and Assay.  It looks like a straight alphabetical sort gives the desired ordering, with name inverted as in your example

```
DF1 <- DF1[order(file, -Name, Assay)]
```

Create a dummy column that is the value in GT, or else a space if the value in GT `is.na()`

```
DF1[, GT.space := ifelse(is.na(GT), ' ', GT)]
```

Perform the collapsing by Name

```
DF1[, .(GT_concatenated = paste(GT.space, collapse='')), by=.(file, Name)]
```

With my version of your data, this outputs

```
        file Name GT_concatenated
1: file1.csv Fred          AGGTTC
2: file1.csv Curt          GGAGTT
3: file2.csv Fred           AG TC
```

If you really don't want the file column, then

```
DF1[, .(GT_concatenated = paste(GT.space, collapse='')), by=.(file, Name)][, .(Name, GT_concatenated)]
```

yields

```
   Name GT_concatenated
1: Fred          AGGTTC
2: Curt          GGAGTT
3: Fred           AG TC
```